# How to remove .meta extension of Red5 audio file?

Tags: audio, red5

On our site, people record audio live then it's saved to our VPS with Red5 as an flv. For some reason, the saved audio files have a .meta extension and there doesn't seem to be an audio file generated that's just .flv without the .meta extension.

Our previous server did it fine but it doesn't seem to work on the new one. Our hosting company can't help.

Question: how to remove the .meta extension?

THank you!!!

Comment: Who knows...  You've provided no code showing what you're saving, or anything.  It's unlikely we can help you if you cannot provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

The meta is generated whenever someone streams the file for the first time. If these files do not exist there is a delay in playback while it is generated. If you do not want these files you will need to override the media reader class to prevent them from being used or created. For an flv this class is org.red5.io.flv.impl.FLVReader.